# How to use "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm following the docs and toying with simple_form, formtastic, and nested_form gems with no success. This very simple example yields empty for for me:

### resort.rb

```
class Resort < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :description, :latitude, :longitude, :name, :phone, :second_name,
                  :resort_type_id, :infrastructure_attributes

  validates_presence_of :name, :address, :phone, :description

  has_many :infrastructures
  belongs_to :resort_type

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :infrastructures
end
```

### infrastructure.rb

```
class Infrastructure < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :infrastructure_type_id, :resort_id

  belongs_to :resort
  belongs_to :infrastructure_type
end
```

### form view

```
= form_for @resort do |f|
  = f.fields_for :infrastructures do |i|
    = i.text_field :name
```

Seems I missed something obvious but can't figure out what exactly is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may ask, in your controller action did you build the appropriate code for your infrastructure. Something like
 3.times { @resort = @resort.infrastrucures.build }

To my knowledge you need something like this for your form before it can build the proper nested form content

Comment: I totally miss it, seems you are right. I would do a bit more testing before marking your answer, but I'm sure it correct, thank you for the tip!

Comment: The `@resort.infrastrucures.build` in the #new method is enough, but in general it is exactly what should be done for the nested form.